# Ansible search sublists for value

Tags: ansible

A webhook triggers an AWX job and I want to run the deployment on a certain host depending on the service, since they run on different servers. I need to know which server uses that service to set is as a var so it can be used as a host in the following play.

My variable inside vars.yaml looks like this:

```
staging_hosts:
  server1: ['service1', 'service2', 'service3']
  server2: ['service4', 'service5', 'service6']
  server3: ['service7', 'service8', 'service9']
```

Playbook:

```
- name: write deployment hosts
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    deployment_hosts: absent
  vars_files:
    - ./group_vars/vars.yaml
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        modified_repos: (small regex filter to find modified repository)
    - set_fact:
        deployment_hosts: "{{ item }}"
      when: '{{ modified_repos }} in {{ item }}'
      with_list:
        - "{{ staging_hosts }}"

- name: connect to Cluster
  hosts: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['deployment_hosts'] }}"
```

What can I do against this warning and error?

```
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{ modified_repos }} in {{ item }}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '{{ modified_repos }} in {{ item }}' failed. True {% else %} False {% endif %}): unhashable type: 'list'
```

Oh I forgot to mention. It is important, that deployment_hosts could also contain two hosts if modified repos include for example service1 and service4.

Comment: You don't need Jinja templating delimiters `{{ }}` in `when:` condition as the error says. Remove them and try.

Comment: Thanks, full error now: AILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'modified_repos in item' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if modified_repos in item %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): unhashable type: 'list'\n\nThe error appears to be in [...]  but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    - debug: msg=\"{{ modified_repos }}\"\n    - set_fact:\n      ^ here\n"}

Comment: Not sure what's in `modified_repos`, but should it be `when: item in modified_repos`?

Comment: modified_repos is an array of strings in the format 'service1' till 'service9', as these are modified repositories which triggered the webhook and i want deployed. therefore I'm searching, which server inside staging_hosts includes the service depicted in modified_repos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"deployment_hosts could also contain two hosts if modified repos include for example service1 and service4."*

A: Use [intersect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) filter. For example, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    staging_hosts:
      server1: ['service1', 'service2', 'service3']
      server2: ['service4', 'service5', 'service6']
      server3: ['service7', 'service8', 'service9']
    modified_repos: ['service1', 'service4']

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        deployment_hosts: "{{ deployment_hosts|default([]) + [item.key] }}"
      loop: "{{ staging_hosts|dict2items }}"
      when: modified_repos|intersect(item.value)|length > 0
    - debug:
        var: deployment_hosts
```

gives

```yaml
  deployment_hosts:
  - server1
  - server2
```